# Pylint UnicodeDecodeError utf-8 can't decode byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint, pylintrc

When I run pylint installed with pip (version 2.1.1 and Python V.3.7) in windows 10, I get this error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte.

How do we fix it?

Here is the screenshot
[image: Pylint error]

Comment: Please add python version information, pylint version information, the file content which you are trying to validate.

Comment: @arsho I edited with version information. When I just run pylint in cmd it gives this error

Comment: Can you add the python file you are trying to use with pylint?
Does the program run successfully?

Comment: I am not checking any python file. Just to check if pylint is installed properly, I am running just pylint in terminal.

Comment: I installed `pylint` inside virtual environment and could use it. Take a look at this https://gist.github.com/arsho/98acacd6c83320e227aa9bd9fed99b35  . You may try to install pylint in virtual environment without using the existing `site-packages` like this procedure.

Comment: Yes I have tried it and still I get the same error

Answer (score 29):

If you haven't already, generate a pylintrc file like this:

```
pylint --generate-rcfile | out-file -encoding utf8 .pylintrc
```

It's important to include the encoding option.